# Who was the first person to be referred to by acronym?

Tags: history, names, historical-figures, acronyms

Rashi, Rambam, the Maharal, the Rosh, the Rema, etc. are all usually referred to by their acronyms. This custom makes sense in a culture that is mostly transmitted through the written word where ink and paper were not cheap - someone wrote רש"י, so I say Rashi.

Who was the first person to be generally addressed as an acronym?  Who popularized the use of that acronym?

Comment: How about רשב"י?

Comment: @sam Is that what he called himself?

Comment: what does "generally addressed" mean? By himself about himself? By contemporaries to his face? By others after his death?

Comment: @Dan That's why I am asking the second question - `Who popularized the use of that acronym?`.  I think "generally addressed" means "at some point in time".

Comment: "someone wrote רש"י, so I say Rashi": it sounds like you're asking specifically and only about acronyms pronounced as such (as opposed, say, to אדה״ר, who is otherwise undeniably the first person to be known by an acronym). If that's the case, you may wish to clarify it in your question.

Comment: @msh210, technically, that's what an acronym is. If it is not pronounced as such, it is just a generic abbreviation.

Comment: @sam, most Tannaim are abbreviated in Mishnayoth, are they not?

Comment: I'm happy closing this.  The answer in the linked question is an answer to this question.  Good find, @yydl, I've added the acronym tag.

Answer (score 4):

A possible candidate would be the Amora אביי - whose real name was נחמני but was called אביי  by the acronym for אֲשֶׁר-בְּךָ יְרֻחַם יָתוֹם. Read more details [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%99).

Unless you want to argue it was Avraham Avinu: אַבְרָהָם, כִּי אַב-הֲמוֹן גּוֹיִם נְתַתִּיךָ

Answer (score 0):

Some people (I believe erroneously) claim that Maccabee is from Mi Chamocha B'elim YHWH.  If that is the case, I go with Judah the Maccabee. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maccabees